# Error SQLSTATE [HY000] [1045]

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, cpanel, blogs

I'm currently working on a Laravel project. I did the deploy on a shared server, but I get the error message

> "SQLSTATE [HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root' @ 'localhost' (using password: NO)"

The project in Local works me correctly, but on the server it's limited to error only. I configured the environment variables in my .env

I think that the server probably does not read the .env file and that is why the problem arises.

Comment: First of all, you should **_not_** be using `root` to login to your sql database. The database should have it's own account with specified access, instead of **_all_** access that root gets. It's very dangerous. Secondly, your access is denied, and that means ROOT probably has a password, which you are not using.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow+SQLSTATE+%5BHY000%5D+%5B1045%5D&oq=stackoverflow+SQLSTATE+%5BHY000%5D+%5B1045%5D&gs_l=psy-ab.3...9710.9888.0.10127.2.2.0.0.0.0.113.217.0j2.2.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.1.112...0j0i10k1.0.MyOrEX3TrLM

Comment: @bassxzero Thanks! I created a new database and created a new user. Then I changed the data in my .env file as specified by Laravel.

Previously, I loaded projects into Laravel but I was not using databases. But the problem continues.

It seems the changes in my .env file are not recognized by the Hosting

Answer (score 1):

Clear your cache on live server by adding and running this route:

```
Route::get('/clear-cache', function() {
    $exitCode = Artisan::call('cache:clear');
    // return what you want
});
```

Comment: You should never modify this file, this is the point and purpose of the .env

Comment: @Options which file ?

Comment: the database.php file

Answer (score 0):

You have to add your proper database credentials to .env file .. you can find the database credentials in cPanel

Comment: I've changed my data in the .env file (according to the data in my database, I've switched to production as well)

I also changed the "Debug" mode to false but the error is still displayed. It seems the changes in my .env file are not recognized by the Hosting

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem was with my Hosting.

My best option was to start using **DigitalOcean**.

But at that moment what I did was:

- Create a new database.
- Create a new user.
- Add the new data in my .env file as specified by Laravel.
- Create a route to clear the cache as Junaid Ahmad specified but by changing some things.

`Route::get('/cache', function() {
        $clear = Artisan::call('cache:clear');
        return "Cache cleared";
    });`

I take this opportunity to thank those people who helped me at that time.

And if you are going through this: Avoid at all costs modifying the **database.php** file. This isn't a good practice... And change your hosting for a DigitalOcean VPS.